# unable to install python module

Tags: command-line

In ubuntu17.10 operating system and I am using python3.6. When I'm trying to install a new module in it shows the following problem.

```
root@saif-ahmad:~# ***sudo apt-get install python3-pip***
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnih-dbus1 libpango1.0-0 libpangox-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@saif-ahmad:~# ***sudo pip3 install numpy***
Collecting numpy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 350, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 837, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connection.py", line 323, in connect
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 324, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 814, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1068, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just do `apt install python3-numpy` instead?

Comment: Why is your user root? Also why the *** before and after the command?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to be root to install software, that's why you use sudo.
You should log in as your normal user and just do

```
sudo apt install python3-numpy
```